# My Keras Sequential Model is giving me a 0 accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

---

I'm trying to create a model that could predict the premier league games results. And when trying to do this the model keeps giving me 50 - 66 accuracy when training and 0 when testing with some test data.
I just started using keras and tensorflow so I apologize for the bad code

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Dropout

x_train = np.random.randint(0, 43, size=(4000, 2))
x_test = np.random.randint(0, 43, size=(2000, 2))
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4000))
y_test = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(2000))

model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Embedding(5000, 43),
        keras.layers.Conv1D(
            filters=43, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"
        ),
        keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
        keras.layers.LSTM(100),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
acc = model.evaluate(x_test)
print(acc)
```

This is the output:

```
----

Epoch 1/5
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6716 - accuracy: 0.5663

Epoch 2/5
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6320 - accuracy: 0.6357

Epoch 3/5
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6244 - accuracy: 0.6457

Epoch 4/5
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6208 - accuracy: 0.6578

Epoch 5/5
125/125 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6183 - accuracy: 0.6585

**89/89 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00**

**[0.0, 0.0]**
```

Comment: Can't be preproduced without the respective data. Try to at least reproduce this with randomly generated inputs first or a publicly available dataset.

Comment: ok srry bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to supply the target data for evaluation. i.e.

```
acc = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```